# Restrict IO usage using cgroups

Tags: linux, performance, io, centos, cgroups

I am trying to restrict Io usage on my server using cgroups.

Here is my partition table info:

```
major minor  #blocks  name    
   8        0   10485760 sda
   8        1    9437184 sda1
   8        2    1047552 sda2
```

Here is my Filesystem structure:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       8.9G  8.4G   37M 100% /
none           1004M     0 1004M   0% /dev/shm
```

When i am trying to execute the following command:

> echo "8:1 10485760" > 
>   /cgroup/blkio/test2/blkio.throttle.write_bps_device

I get the output as :

```
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

Here is my cgroups configuration:

```
mount { 
    blkio = /cgroup/blkio;      
}

group test2 {
    blkio {
        blkio.throttle.write_iops_device="";
        blkio.throttle.read_iops_device="";
        blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="";
        blkio.throttle.read_bps_device="";
        blkio.weight="";
        blkio.weight_device="";
    }
}
```

Why i can not restrict the /dev/sda1 IO usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the physical device when setting up blkio. Use the major:minor for the whole disk (8:0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it works for the read restriction but i want to restrict io write operation i have set the blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="8:0 10485760";